# Оптимизация изображений, под различные разрешения экрана

Tags: unity3d

Здравствуйте, хочу узнать, необходимо ли в Unity, под разные разрешения устройства добавлять в проект изображения соответствующие разрешениям. Допустим, добавляю изображение под 2K экраны, на устройстве с 2K выглядит замечательно, но если запустить приложение на слабом устройстве с HD разрешением, то приложение будет тормозить. Сейчас вижу единственное решение это определять разрешение экрана и использовать из Resources заготовленные картинки для данного разрешения. Проблема: Большой размер apk, а на iOS вообще около 1гб. Возможно ли в Unity как-то искуственно менять разрешения спрайтов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш вариант для решения этой проблемы, является довольно частой практикой. При этом чтобы уменьшить размеры сборок можно применить [Asset Bundles](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/Manual/AssetBundlesIntro.html), это позволит вам запаковать текстуры разного разрешения по разным бандлам и при запуске приложения скачивать нужный бандл в зависимости от разрешения экрана.

Если для вас важна скорость запуска приложения (вы не хотите чтобы пользователь при первом запуске ждал какое-то время, пока скачается  бандл с нужной графикой) - часть арта, необходимую для первых шагов в приложении (например первых 3-5 уровней в игре типа match-3) можно оставить в сборке в формате максимального разршенения, что позволит вам в фоне загрузить необходимые бандлы и скрыть момент загрузки от пользователя.

Также используйте [сжатие текстур](https://docs.unity3d.com/560/Documentation/Manual/class-TextureImporter.html), в Unity 2017 версий было добавлено множество вариантов сжатия текстур, которые позволять вам уменьшить размер сборки. Однако, с этим есть свои нюансы, например самое эффективное сжатие для iOS - PVRTC, может оставлять артефакты на текстурах, где используется прозрачность, но для больших background текстур без прозрачности этот варинат подойдет отлично.

Еще можете попробовать сжать исходное изображение, для этого есть много сервисов по типу [TinyPNG](https://tinypng.com/), в данном случае проблем с прозрачностью проблем не будет, но так как это сжатие работает путем уменьшения диапазона используемых цветов в изображении, могут возникнуть проблемы с градиентами.

Если не хотите использовать графику во многих разрешениях в проекте, то можете попрбовать дробить ее на большее количество атласов меньшего разрешения, что положительно скажется на скорости загрузки таких текстур в память. Для примера, 4к background текстуру можно разрезать на 2 текстуры 2к и загружать в приложении как префаб.